# Sending Binary files over a socket. Text files work, nothing else does?

Tags: c++, sockets, file-io

I can send very large text files no problem. I try to send a jpg, etc and it wont work. The file is the correct size. I don't know what I'm missing.. I check my read and write functions by writing the data before sending to a temp.foo file. I check it, and it handles anything.

I send it like this

```
for(vector< .... >::iterator it = v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it ){
    pair<...> p=*it;
    send(s,p.first,p.second,0);
}
```

Then the other program reads it

```
    for(i = 0; i < size; i+=max){
    b= 0;
    while (b== 0) {
        if ((b = recv(s, buf, max, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
}
    stringstream ss;
    ss << buf;
    char * out = (char*)malloc(b); 
    memcpy(out,buff,numbytes);// Perhaps my error is here?
}
// write function call here
```

Comment: Show how you open the files, you are probably opening them in text mode.

Comment: Hi Dani. If you follow the link at the bottom I included the read / write methods. I have them in binary. The r/w is fine, but somewhere between reading, sending, and writing somethings happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some general points about handling binary data:

1. Make sure you open the input and output files in binary mode, such as with the [`ios::binary`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) flag or the ["rb"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/) or ["wb"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/) format. The default is text mode, which will mangle end-of-line characters in a binary file.
2. Binary files can have NUL bytes (`\0`), which means you can't use string-handling functions that work on NUL-terminated strings. C strings are not NUL safe. For instance, this code won't fill `ss` properly since it interprets `buf` as a NUL-terminated string:

   ```
   stringstream ss;
   ss << buf;
   ```

Also, on the line you point out, is `buff` with two `f`s a typo? On the other lines you reference `buf` with one `f`.

```
memcpy(out,buff,numbytes);// Perhaps my error is here?
```

Comment: Oh that's just a typo. I call ss.str().c_str(). I am reading it with  ofstream myFile (fn, ios::out | ios::binary);

Comment: Huh. Soon as I change it back. It starts working. This might have been a case of overworked programmer..